# How to get changes in database done by someone else?

Tags: drush

We are working on features in team. My team-mate have done some changes & synced the cloud database.

I also have some database changes locally, now I want those changes in database which he synced.

I can't use `drush sql-sync` becauses it asks to drop all the tables. So my local changes will gone.

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike code Database changes cannot be synced easily.

Try using [Features Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) This module exports your database settings to code so that they can be added to Version Control took like Git.

Tip : Create one feature for every independent functionality, so that it will be easy to manage. There are other supporting module for Features, which can reduce your efforts.